How to Properly Apply Tailwind CSS Styles to Next.js Image Component with Relative Positioning
I am trying to use the Next.js Image component in my React project with Tailwind CSS, but I am encountering issues with applying relative positioning styles and other specific styles like objectFit. The problem seems to stem from the container div that Next.js automatically creates around the img tag. Here is my current code:
<section style={{ position: 'relative', width: '100vw', height: '56.25vw', maxHeight: '500px' }}>
  <Image
    src={carouselItem.image}
    alt={`Slide ${carouselItem.text}`}
    layout="fill"
    objectFit="cover"
    className="object-cover object-center aspect-video"
  />
</section>


encountering issues with applying relative positioning styles. Could you please elaborate what issues are encountered? It behaves as expected when I tried the code. Note that the styles specified using Image props will overwrite the ones from tailwind classes.

Though you are not specific with the issues you are encountering, I do see an issue with how you are trying to style your Image. Specifically, the "layout" and "objectFit" props are unnecessary as they have been removed in favor of className or style applied to the image. See the link below for further details:
Next JS Image (Legacy)
Remove those props, and use your Tailwind classes to style your image. That might be enough to fix your problem.
